# module.exports cannot find module

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I wanted to make a help command for the bot which shows the prefix of the specific guild. Here is my `help.js` file :-

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: 'Neptune Premium Commands',
    execute(client, message, args){
        const { guildPrefix } = require('../../main.js');

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(`Prefix : ${guildPrefix}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL( {dynamic: true} ))
        .setDescription(`Neptune Premium Commands List.`)
        .addFields(
            {name: `moderation`, value: '`kick` `ban` `lock` `unlock` `purge` `warn` `delwarn` `mute` `unmute`'},
            {name: `utility`, value: '`prefix` `timedif` `greet` `userinfo` `serverinfo` `snipe`'},
            {name: `misc`, value: '`help` `support` `vote` `invite`'}
        )
        .setFooter(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL( {dynamic: true} ))

        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
}
```

Once I use `$help` it shows Prefix as **undefined**

Here is my `main.js` file :-

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');

const config = require('./config.json');

const prefix = require('discord-prefix');

const defaultPrefix = config.prefix;

// .. ignoring some part of the code ...

client.on('message', message =>{
    
    // prefix db part
    if (!message.guild) return;

    let guildPrefix = prefix.getPrefix(message.guild.id);

    if (!guildPrefix) guildPrefix = defaultPrefix;

    if(message.content === '<@!849854849351942144>'){
        message.channel.send(`My Prefix is \`${guildPrefix}\`. Use \`${guildPrefix}help\` for my commands!`)
    }

    if(message.channel.type === 'dm') return;

    // discord.js command handler
    if(!message.content.startsWith(guildPrefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(guildPrefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(cmd) || client.commands.find(command => command.aliases && command.aliases.includes(cmd));

// ...
```

I have ignored some part of the main code and only put the prefix part. I'm using a package called `discord-prefix` for this.

Comment: How are you exporting your `prefix` in `main.js`?

Comment: I'm first exporting it from `config.json` by `const defaultPrefix = config.prefix;` and then `guildPrefix` for a particular guild. shall I send my `main.js` file?

Comment: Yeah, just update it to your question, this might help us fixing your problem :D

Comment: Sure, I've updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're getting `undefinded` when `requiring` the `prefix` from your `main.js` is that you're never `exporting` a `value`.

If you'd want to get your `prefix` by using `require` you have to do this:

#### main.js

```js
const serverPrefix = '!';
exports.prefix = serverPrefix;

// This would also work:
module.exports.prefix = serverPrefix;
```

#### help.js

```js
const { prefix } = require('./main.js');

// Or:

const prefix = require('./main.js').prefix;
```

You can read more about exporting [`here`](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/)

---

But you are using a `npm package` called [`discord-prefix`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-prefix) and if you take a look at the examples you should notice that there are two interesting methods:

- `.setPrefix()`
- `.getPrefix()`

So if you want to get the prefix that you assigned in you `main.js`, in your `help.js` you have to use the `.getPrefix()` function. But before you can to this you have to **set** your prefix with `.setPrefix()` **first**:

#### main.js

```js
const prefix = require('discord-prefix');

// This is optional, you could also use message.guild instead
const { guild } = message

if(!prefix.getPrefix(guild.id)) prefix.setPrefix('!', guild.id);
```

And after that you can get your prefix with the `.getPrefix` function:

#### help.js

```js
const prefix = require('discord-require');
const { guild } = message;

const guildPrefix = prefix.getPrefix(guild.id);
```

---

#### Alternatively...

...you can use a `.env` file. This is much simpler (in my opinion) and I used it too, before moving all `per-server-settings` to a `database`. Therefore you have to install [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and create a file named `.env`

Now, if you want to set a `prefix` for your **`bot`** (**not** for specific servers) you want to set it like this:

#### Example

```
PREFIX = !
LOGINTOKEN = 1234567890
WELCOMECHANNEL = 3213213212321

// and so on...
```

Now that you have successfully created your `.env` file and defined some `variables` you have to `require` that new package in your `main.js`:

#### main.js

```js
require ('dotenv').config()
```

Now you're ready to go and you can get your defined `variables` **anywhere** like this:

#### help.js

```js
// You dont have to assign it to a variable
const prefix = process.env.PREFIX

// This schema will work for every variable you defined in .env:
process.env.LOGINTOKEN

process.env.WELCOMECHANNEL

// and so on...
```

---

#### Note

Please make sure you add the `.env` file to your `.gitignore` (if you're using git to store your code)

Comment: oh my gosh that's a lot of info and thanks a lot!! I'll update my code asap

Comment: No problem, we’re here to help ^^

Comment: And let me know if your code works now ^^

Comment: That’s great ^^